# Button that changes a boolean value tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a button in Tkinter  that acts as the first button in a game so I want it to start the game and also destroy itself so the player can start playing, but I can't seem to get it to work.


Here is my code so far, any help would be much appreciated:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import seed
from random import randint
from tkinter import font as font
import time

root = Tk()
myFont = font.Font(size=25)
root.title("Python Guessing Game")
root.geometry("600x600")

ready = False;


if ready == True:
  print('Hello! What is your name ?')
  destroyBtn()



button_start = Button(root, text="Start Game", font=myFont, bg='#0052cc', fg='#ffffff', command=ready 
   = True, height=1, width=20).place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

def destroyBtn():
   button_start.destroy()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello I've coded a quick sample of what I believe you are looking for. If this does not solve this issue please expand on what you are looking for.

```
from tkinter import *

gameStarted = False

def startGame():
    gameStarted = True
    print("The game status is now:" + str(gameStarted))
    myButton.destroy()
    print("The button is now destroyed.")


root = Tk()
myButton = Button(root, text="start game", command=startGame)
myButton.pack(fill=BOTH)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hello, i tried this and it just destroys the whole program and i what im looking for was just to destroy the button itself. and thanks for answering

Comment: Fixed it. Now it will destroy the button.